# Safari nestled scrollbar bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I've come across this interesting bug where basically the user can't scroll down a text that's been nestled inside a div. This problem doesn't seem to happen in other browsers but Safari.

I made a quick file to better showcase the bug, and I hope to hear from suggestions on how I could fix this for Safari users without us having to rebuild the entire site. As you can see after clicking Next, the Terms of Service is unscrollable. It scrolls fine in other browsers.

File here: http://private.edenvitae.com/files/32864708/test.html

Answer (score 0):

Safari needs extra support try this

```
  * {-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;overflow-y:visible}
```

Comment: Just tried this, no change, scrolling still not working. Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Using a plugin to replace the browser's built-in scrolling is not the solution I was hoping for, but I guess it is a work around. By the way, in my testings NiceScroll was a really bad plugin, it slows down the browser and breaks the website's design. Perfect Scrollbar was much better. https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar

Comment: Great thanks even i was facing the same issue the ios devices lags on nice scroll i will try perfect scrollbar